# Find years with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Dear, i would delete from a list, the strings that contain a date.
Ex: "1990s music groups" must be deleted.

Can I do this in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `YYYY` date format, the regular expression `^\d{4}` should work for any date in the beginning of the String.

```
String str = "1990s music groups";
boolean shouldDelete = str.matches("^\d{4}");
if (shouldDelete) {
    // Delete string
}
```

If you want to match the date in any part of the String, simply remove the leading `^`.

Answer (score 5):

The regex `\d{4}` would probably suffice - it will match all strings containing 4 subsequent digits. You can perhaps have some more specific cases, like `19\d{2}|20\d{2}`

Answer (score 0):

```
//ArrayList<String> list = ....
String year = "1990";
ArrayList<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String str:list) {
   if (str.matches(".*"+year+".*")) {
      toRemove.add(str);
   }
}
for (String str:toRemove) list.remove(str);
toRemove = null;
```

Use a toRemove list to prevent a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: if you want any date use \d{4} like Bozho suggested instead of a year variable

Answer (score 0):

For a more specific year rate (1970-2029)  I've used:

```
Pattern pattern;
Matcher matcher;
String errorTag = null;
private static final String PATTERN_YEAR = "^(197\\d{1}|198\\d{1}|199\\d{1}|200\\d{1}|201\\d{1}|202\\d{1})";
```

...

```
if (filter.getName().contains("YYYY")){
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_YEAR);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(filter.getValue());
      if(!matcher.matches()){   
          errorTag= " *** The year is invalid, review the rate";


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am landing here every time I search for regex for validating year and I tried all the answers but couldn't get it work properly finally the following regex worked for me

```
^(19|20)\d{2}$
```